# Point coordinate shift after python toolbox processing

Tags: arcpy, point, coordinates

I am working on custom clustering in ArcMap. For it I have created a python toolbox, where I do the processing. However, as a result I get slightly shifted points (6-20 meters), while they shall stay the same and just be grouped:
[image: Points example]

```
    point = arcpy.Point()

    # Spatial reference definition
    desc = arcpy.Describe(nodes)
    spatial_ref = desc.spatialReference


    for key in clustering.keys():
        cluster = 'CMPMT_Cluster_' + str(key)
        out_cluster = os.path.join(output_dir, 'DataTest.gdb', cluster)
        if len(clustering[key].keys()) > 1:
            point_list = []
            for k in clustering[key].keys():
                if k != 'tot_cost':
                    point.X = clustering[key][k]['XY'][0]
                    point.Y = clustering[key][k]['XY'][1]
                    point_geometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
                    point_list.append(point_geometry)

            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(point_list, out_cluster)
            arcpy.DefineProjection_management(out_cluster, spatial_ref)
```

I have checked the coordinates that are passed and they are fine, also I save another point file with the same spatial reference and it is okay. What could be the problem?

UPD: as Vince in comments suggested, I have examined how I pass the spatial reference to the geometry object. With the current updated code it works as needed:

```
point_geometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, spatial_ref)      
point_list.append(point_geometry)      
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(point_list, out_cluster)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show how the spatial reference is defined, what the map frame spatial reference contains, and to quantify the value of "slightly shifted" (e.g., 1.36 meters). Generally speaking, you should define the spatial reference of a data layer **before** placing data in it; you may just be corrupting the result by doing so after.

Comment: @Vince Thank you for your answer, Vince. I simply take the spatial reference from the input data:

`# Get the spatial reference from the input so that the results can be mapped to the original data
    desc = arcpy.Describe(nodes)
    spatial_ref = desc.spatialReference`

I will check your idea. It looks slightly, but the biggest difference so far is 19 meters.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to comb comments for critical information.  You almost certainly have an incorrect datum handling situation here.

Comment: @Vince, I have put in what I understood from your request. I am not sure what you mean by _map frame spatial reference_

Comment: @Vince thank you for giving me an idea, where to look for a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend supplying the Spatial Reference to createPoint geometry.

point_geometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, spatial_ref).

Also, create the out_cluster FC with the spatial reference, then append to that feature class.

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.join(output_dir, 'DataTest.gdb'), cluster, "Point", "", "", "", spatial_ref)